# Problema de encoding ao extrair arquivo zip - editado

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo-zip, python-requests

Um webhook chama minha API enviando uma requisição POST.
No body da requisição contem a url de um arquivo ZIP.

Utilizando a biblioteca requests, realizo um GET na url do arquivo.
Eu preciso extrair este alguns arquivos deste zip e realizar uma série de processos.
O problema é que ao tentar extrair o arquivo me deparo com a seguinte mensagem de erro:
O seguinte erro ocorre:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xa2' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Código da requisição e tentativa de extrair o arquivo:

```py
import io
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile

response = requests.get(url)

with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip: # respose.content = arquivo zip em bytes por isso usei io.BytesIO()
    thezip.extractall()
```

Quando dou um print na lista de nomes do arquivo:

```py
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip:
    print(thezip.namelist())
```

```
['Nao_Consistido/', 'Nao_Consistido/Relat\xc2\xa2rio de Previs\xc3\x86o de Vaz\xc3\x86o - Limite Inferior - LI.xls', 'Nao_Consistido/Relat\xc2\xa2rio de Previs\xc3\x86o de Vaz\xc3\x86o - Limite Superior - LS.xls', 'Nao_Consistido/Relat\xc2\xa2rio_de_Previs\xc3\x86o de Vaz\xc3\xa4es_PMO_de_DEZEMBRO_2019-preliminar.xls', 'Nao_Consistido/Todos_LI.prv', 'Nao_Consistido/Todos_LS.prv', 'Nao_Consistido/Todos_VE.prv']
```

Já defini a variável de ambiente PYTHONIOENCODING para utf-8 e não funcionou. 
EDIT:
Após alguns testes percebi que o problema ocorre apenas no servidor(sistema linux), localmente no Windows 10 não ocorre.

Comment: E o que seria a "lista de nomes do arquivo"?

Comment: O método .namelist(), lista o nome dos arquivos dentro do zip

Comment: Que método `namelist`? Não tem nada disso no código da sua pergunta. Poderia verificar se postou o código completo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Gustavo, ainda não dá pra entender bem o seu problema, porém você poderia explicar porque está usando `i.BytesIO` para passar um _path_ para `ZipFile`? Porque você não passa uma _string_ normal? Ou ainda, qual o conteúdo de `response.content`? `\xa2` é o caractere `¢`, se o nome do seu arquivo tem este caractere pode ser a fonte do seu problema. Enfim, são sugestões de melhoria da sua pergunta, do jeito que está agora está difícil definir corretamente seu problema.

Comment: Utilizo o `i.BytesIO` porque o response.content me devolve o arquivo bytes

Comment: Mas com BytesIO você vai seguir tendo bytes... Eu aconselho você a converter seus bytes em string, você pode usar `str(response.content', encoding='utf-8')` (use o _encoding_ correto da sua requisição [#docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)).

Comment: Ao tentar converter recebo um erro parecido: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é usar o encode e decode:

```
import io
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile

response = requests.get(url)

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip:
        for i in thezip.namelist():
                n = Path(i.encode('cp437').decode(encoding))
                if 1:
                    print(n)
                if i[-1] == '/':
                    if not n.exists():
                        n.mkdir()
                else:
                    with n.open('wb') as w:
                        w.write(thezip.read(i))
```

Comment: Acredito que esteja faltando parte do código, algumas variáveis usadas não estão definidas.

Comment: O erro mudou para: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 20: invalid start byte`

Answer (score -1):

No python, assim como em outras linguagens, interpreta `\` como uma String escape, tente separar a path do arquivo zip com `/`.

Comment: Poderia da um exemplo? Devo separar o path antes de extrair?

Comment: Um caminho direto - C:/Users/Nome/Desktop/Arquivo.zip , esse modulo requests ele captura o caminho passado e faz a separação de cada diretório utilizando como condição de separação o carácter ```/``` até o arquivo desejado.